# Make system services dependent on another service

Tags: linux, rhel, systemd, services

How to make system services dependent on another system service.
For eg:

There are 2 services in RedHat 7

```
ntpd.service    
ntpdate.service
```

How to make `ntpdate` dependent on `ntpd` service?
If `ntpd` is stopped/started `ntpdate` also gets stopped/started.

I guess it has something to do with this file

```
$ cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/ntpdate.service

[Unit]
Description=Set time via NTP

After=syslog.target network.target nss-lookup.target

Before=time-sync.target

Wants=time-sync.target
```

Any suggestion what/where to make changes ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the 'proper' or 'best' way, but you could write a simple daemon that monitors the status of ntpd.service every 5 seconds and starts/stops ntpdate.service as necessary?